ssl.SSLEOFError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol
Python version: 3.11
boto3 version: 1.35.20
Goal: Read compressed parquet files from Amazon bucket and store data in a json.gz file in local VM.
I have the following code to achieve my goal:
def retrieve_s3_bucket(bucket_name: str, 
                           access_key_id: str,
                           secret_access_key: str,
                           region_name: str,
                           prefix: list,
                           parquet_file_list: list,
                           persistent_connections: int):
  client_config = config.Config(
    max_pool_connections=persistent_connections,
  )
 
  session = Session(aws_access_key_id=access_key_id, 
                    aws_secret_access_key=secret_access_key,
                    region_name = region_name)
  s3 = session.resource('s3',config=client_config)
  my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
  
  objects = []
  if parquet_file_list:
    for parquet_file_name in parquet_file_list:
      object_collection = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix+parquet_file_name)
      for object in object_collection:
        objects.append(object)
  else:  
    objects = my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix)
    
  return objects

def read_parquet_file_error_callback(retry_state):
        """
        This function logs stack trace to help debugging
        """
        logging.error(format_exc())

@retry(reraise=True, 
       stop=stop_after_attempt(2), 
       wait=wait_random(min=15, max=30),
       retry=retry_if_exception(retry_if_not_specific_exception_message),
       retry_error_callback=read_parquet_file_error_callback)
def read_parquet_file(object,
                      columns: list,
                      filters: list) -> DataFrame:

  try:
    
    object_name = object.key
    parquet_file_name = os.path.basename(os.path.normpath(object_name))
    buffer = BytesIO()
    object.Object().download_fileobj(buffer)
  
    if filters:
      df_object = read_parquet(buffer,
                               columns=columns,
                               filters=filters)
    else:
      df_object = read_parquet(buffer,
                               columns=columns) 
    
    ## Change the type of the column to reduce size
    if len(columns)>1:
      df_object_optimize = optimize_float_columns(df_object)
    else:
      df_object_optimize = df_object
    
    return df_object_optimize
  except Exception as e:
    logging.error(f"{object_name}: {str(e)}")
    print(str(e))
    raise  

def get_data_from_bucket(objects,
                          columns_to_read: list,
                          columns_to_format: list,
                          workers: int,
                          filters: list) -> DataFrame:
  
  list_dfs = []
  futures = []

  with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as executor:
    # submit tasks and collect futures
    futures = [executor.submit(read_parquet_file,object,columns_to_read,filters) for object in objects]
    # wait for all tasks to complete
    wait(futures)
    
    for future in futures:
      df_object = future.result()
      if df_object.empty:
        print("Empty")
      else:  
        list_dfs.append(df_object)
      
  if list_dfs:
    data = concat(list_dfs,ignore_index=True)                   
    return data
  else:
    raise Exception(f"#BREDataNotFound")

I have an azure virtual machine (VM) located in South Central US. The amazon bucket is located in eu-central-1. I am executing this code in parallel with some uipath bots. When I trigger one bot, It is working normally. However, when I trigger more than one bot at the same time in my VM, I am getting the following error:
File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1099, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 653, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 806, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 465, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 509, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 517, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1104, in _create
    self.do_handshake()   File "C:\Program Files\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 1382, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLEOFError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 464, in send
    urllib_response = conn.urlopen(
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 847, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 445, in increment
    raise reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\util.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 793, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "[Folder_Path]\parquet_download.py", line 118, in read_parquet_file
    object.Object().download_fileobj(buffer)   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 890, in object_download_fileobj
    return self.meta.client.download_fileobj(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\boto3\s3\inject.py", line 801, in download_fileobj
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 103, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\futures.py", line 266, in result
    raise self._exception   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\tasks.py", line 269, in _main
    self._submit(transfer_future=transfer_future, **kwargs)   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\s3transfer\download.py", line 354, in _submit
    response = client.head_object(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 565, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 1001, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\client.py", line 1027, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 119, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 202, in _send_request
    while self._needs_retry(
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 354, in _needs_retry
    responses = self._event_emitter.emit(
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 207, in __call__
    if self._checker(**checker_kwargs):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 284, in __call__
    should_retry = self._should_retry(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 320, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 363, in __call__
    checker_response = checker(
                       ^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 247, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\retryhandler.py", line 416, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 281, in _do_get_response
    http_response = self._send(request)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\endpoint.py", line 377, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "[Folder_Path]\.venv\Lib\site-packages\botocore\httpsession.py", line 491, in send
    raise SSLError(endpoint_url=request.url, error=e) botocore.exceptions.SSLError: SSL validation failed for https://[BUCKET_PATH]/part-00006-351acc8a-8748-46a1-ae59-03bcddd62d5c.c000.gz.parquet [SSL: UNEXPECTED_EOF_WHILE_READING] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)

Apparently, there is no restrictions from the bucket side to retrieve data. How could I solve this issue?
